# From Which song come the 40 seconds that Cal listens to on Bracca at the beginning of the game?

Tags: game-music-identification, star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

When you start a new game, Cal is listening to a song that - at least to me - sounds extremely like *The Hu*. However, I fail to recognize the specific song, and it is not part of the regular sound rotation during the game.

The snippet starts at 27 seconds into the game, and lasts till 1:07, as one can hear in [this video](https://youtu.be/weo-Tr0-QqE?list=TLPQMDcwNTIwMjPEXQJWdhxt3Q&t=26).

The song returns only once in the whole game as far as I can tell...

> as when Cal is fighting in the asteroid arena, the song seems to loop.

Which song is played, and is it really from the Mongolian Band *The Hu*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song is, indeed, by *The Hu*, and is called *Sugaan Essena*.

It can be found on *The Hu*'s YouTube channel, under the listing [Sugaan Essena (Original Music from "Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order")](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwutOqv4cGo)

Comment: side note: the [EA song video](https://youtu.be/oJZfEh3EciU) sheds light, that it is not Mongolian text but some other "StarWars Language"